# Accessing 3rd level of array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

Hello lovely humans...

I'm using the Advanced Custom Field plugin for WordPress and I'n trying to figure out how I can access some values from an array in an array in an array.

Here is my array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=;
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=>;
    array(10) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(282)
      ["alt"]=&gt;
      string(12) "Cable bundle"
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(12) "Cable bundle"
      ["caption"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["description"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["mime_type"]=&gt;
      string(9) "image/png"
      ["url"]=&gt;
      string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o.png"
      ["width"]=&gt;
      int(1280)
      ["height"]=&gt;
      int(960)
      ["sizes"]=&gt;
      array(33) {
        ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-220x150.png"
        ["thumbnail-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["thumbnail-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["medium"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-300x225.png"
        ["medium-width"]=&gt;
        int(300)
        ["medium-height"]=&gt;
        int(225)
        ["large"]=&gt;
        string(92) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-1024x768.png"
        ["large-width"]=&gt;
        int(640)
        ["large-height"]=&gt;
        int(480)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-width"]=&gt;
        int(1280)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-height"]=&gt;
        int(960)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-220x150.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-width"]=&gt;
        int(1280)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-height"]=&gt;
        int(960)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-150x150.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-width"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-220x150.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-220x150.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-220x150.png"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["home-page"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6773761367_bc13aec4a5_o-530x250.png"
        ["home-page-width"]=&gt;
        int(530)
        ["home-page-height"]=&gt;
        int(250)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=&gt;
    array(10) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(281)
      ["alt"]=&gt;
      string(7) "Circuit"
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(7) "Circuit"
      ["caption"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["description"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["mime_type"]=&gt;
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["url"]=&gt;
      string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b.jpg"
      ["width"]=&gt;
      int(1024)
      ["height"]=&gt;
      int(768)
      ["sizes"]=&gt;
      array(33) {
        ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-220x150.jpg"
        ["thumbnail-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["thumbnail-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["medium"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-300x225.jpg"
        ["medium-width"]=&gt;
        int(300)
        ["medium-height"]=&gt;
        int(225)
        ["large"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b.jpg"
        ["large-width"]=&gt;
        int(640)
        ["large-height"]=&gt;
        int(480)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-width"]=&gt;
        int(1024)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-height"]=&gt;
        int(768)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-width"]=&gt;
        int(1024)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-height"]=&gt;
        int(768)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-150x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-width"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["home-page"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/6500613825_911abf3799_b-530x250.jpg"
        ["home-page-width"]=&gt;
        int(530)
        ["home-page-height"]=&gt;
        int(250)
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=&gt;
    array(10) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(280)
      ["alt"]=&gt;
      string(9) "TV cables"
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(9) "TV cables"
      ["caption"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["description"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["mime_type"]=&gt;
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["url"]=&gt;
      string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o.jpg"
      ["width"]=&gt;
      int(1280)
      ["height"]=&gt;
      int(800)
      ["sizes"]=&gt;
      array(33) {
        ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["thumbnail-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["thumbnail-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["medium"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-300x187.jpg"
        ["medium-width"]=&gt;
        int(300)
        ["medium-height"]=&gt;
        int(187)
        ["large"]=&gt;
        string(92) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-1024x640.jpg"
        ["large-width"]=&gt;
        int(640)
        ["large-height"]=&gt;
        int(400)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-width"]=&gt;
        int(1280)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-height"]=&gt;
        int(800)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-width"]=&gt;
        int(1280)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-height"]=&gt;
        int(800)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-150x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-width"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["home-page"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5249206215_be7e8572d8_o-530x250.jpg"
        ["home-page-width"]=&gt;
        int(530)
        ["home-page-height"]=&gt;
        int(250)
      }
    }
  }
  [3]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=&gt;
    array(10) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(279)
      ["alt"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(11) "CAT5 Cables"
      ["caption"]=&gt;
      string(0) ""
      ["description"]=&gt;
      string(11) "CAT5 Cables"
      ["mime_type"]=&gt;
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
      ["url"]=&gt;
      string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o.jpg"
      ["width"]=&gt;
      int(1536)
      ["height"]=&gt;
      int(2048)
      ["sizes"]=&gt;
      array(33) {
        ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["thumbnail-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["thumbnail-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["medium"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-225x300.jpg"
        ["medium-width"]=&gt;
        int(225)
        ["medium-height"]=&gt;
        int(300)
        ["large"]=&gt;
        string(92) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-768x1024.jpg"
        ["large-width"]=&gt;
        int(640)
        ["large-height"]=&gt;
        int(853)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-width"]=&gt;
        int(1536)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-2-height"]=&gt;
        int(2048)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-3-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4"]=&gt;
        string(83) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-width"]=&gt;
        int(1536)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-4-height"]=&gt;
        int(2048)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-150x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-width"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-5-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-6-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-7-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-220x150.jpg"
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-width"]=&gt;
        int(220)
        ["cat_post_thumb_sizecategoryposts-8-height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["home-page"]=&gt;
        string(91) "http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1543218761_62cea76758_o-530x250.jpg"
        ["home-page-width"]=&gt;
        int(530)
        ["home-page-height"]=&gt;
        int(250)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the URL stored in `["home-page"]` for each of the four images in the array as it's for the correctly sized image and obviously it needs to loop through the entire array.
Basically, I need to understand how to access that level of the array.
I've done some reading, but I still don't really get it.
Do I need multiple `foreach` loops?

So far I have this:

```
$images = get_field('homepage_image');  

foreach ($images as $key => $image ) {
    foreach ($image as $subkey => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $subsubkey => $subvalue) {
            foreach ($subvalue as $subsubsubkey => $subsubvalue) {
                $imageURL = $subsubvalue ['home-page']; 
                        echo $imageURL;
                        echo "<br />";                               }
                }
            }
        }
```

That seems to output the letter h a few times.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
There's probably a better way of doing it, but I'd like to understand this.

Cheers
Toby

Comment: `$array[0]['image']['sizes']['home-page'];` You could get away with one loop for the first key. `foreach ($array as $value) { echo $value['image']['sizes']['home-page'];}`

Comment: Make sure you check weather or not that exists in the loop to avoid uglay PHP errors:
if(!array_key_exists('image',$value) || !array_key_exists('sizes',$value['image']) || !array_key_exists('home-page',$value['image']['sizes'])) { /*handle the error*/ }

Comment: Mike, stories about you will be told around the fire for generations to come. How one man sacrificed a couple of minutes to find a solution for a shoddy WordPress developer and how that solution worked perfectly, first time. A legend is born.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a multi-level array, you can just refer to the particular item using all keys in one call:

```
$thumbnail_one = $array[0]['image']['sizes']['thumbnail'];
```

In your case, you can loop though just the first level and access each thumbnail within that first level.

```
$array = array(); //your array here
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $imageURL = $item['image']['sizes']['home-page'];
    echo $imageURL, ' <br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2nd version, maybe even better

```
function search_key_recursive($key, $array)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach($array AS $k => $v)
    {
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            $result = array_merge($result, search_key_recursive($key, $v));
        }
        else 
        {   
            if($key === $k)
            {
                array_push($result, $v);
            }           
        }
    }
    return $result;
} 

$r = search_key_recursive('home-page', $myArray);

var_dump($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to avoid declaring item manually and adding it a bit of "spicy" you could start from something like this

```
function search_key_recursive($ay, $search)
{
    array_walk_recursive($ay, function($aItem, $aKey, $search)
    {
        if ($aKey == $search)
        {
            echo $aItem . '<br />';
        }
    }, $search);
}  

search_key_recursive($myArray, 'home-page');
```